# Obtener texto de radio checkeado

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente radio button que lleno con php , necesito traer el texto "automatico" o "manual" si este esta checkeado he intentado con esto sin resultado:

```
$('input[name=tipo-caja]:checked').text();




<section>
                                <label>
                                    Tipo Caja
                                </label>
                                <div >
                                    <label class="radio">
                                        <input id="tipo-caja-manual" name="tipo-caja" type="radio" value="1" <?php if (isset($auto))if ($auto->caja=="1"){ ?> 
                                            checked=""            
                                          <?php } ?>>
                                            <i>
                                            </i>
                                            Manual
                                        </input>
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio">
                                        <input id="tipo-caja-auto" name="tipo-caja" type="radio" value="0" <?php if (isset($auto))if ($auto->caja=="0"){ ?> 
                                            checked=""            
                                          <?php } ?>>
                                            <i>
                                            </i>
                                            Automatica
                                        </input>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </section>
```

Comment: Solo como comentario Checkbox != Radio, en tu código lo que generas son elementos de tipo Radio Button, los cuales son diferentes a un Checkbox

Comment: editado gracias !

Comment: Además no existen como tal los tags `</input>` porque un input es un elemento de tipo vacío, que adentro de este no contiene texto, otra razón más que un elemento input no te regresará nada con una función `text()` de jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te recomiendo es manejar valores o atributos de tipo `value` en tus radio button, y en base a el valor que obtenas `val()` lo procesas con `if/else` o `switch` según se te acomode, porque los `input`no tienen texto como tal que puedas obtener por `text()` entonces tendrías que aventarte un selector impráctico para simular lo que quieres. Te dejo este ejemplo donde genero lo que buscas de una forma sencilla pero algo diferente a tu propuesta inicial. Espero te sirva.

```js
$('input[name="tipo-caja"]').on('click', function(){
 console.log($(this).val());
  if ($(this).val() === "1"){
   alert("Manual")
  }
  else {
   alert("Automático")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type ='radio' name ='tipo-caja' value='1'/>Manual
<input type ='radio' name ='tipo-caja' value='2'/>Automático
```

Comment: tenia en cuenta hacer un if else, pero pesaba que podia ser mas simple como actualmente uso $('input[name=tipo-caja]:checked').val() para traer el value pensaba que el texto del input se podia traer con menos código :/

Comment: gracias por la ayuda estimado !

Answer (score 0):

No seria mas facil poner el valor que buscas en el valor del radio asi:

```
$('input[name="tipo-caja"]').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
})

<input type ='radio' name ='tipo-caja' value='Manual'/>Manual
<input type ='radio' name ='tipo-caja' value='Automático'/>Automático
```